# extension from home or extension to home

Tags: word-usage

We are working on a preschool flyer.  We describe ourselves as an extension from home.  Is it extension from home or extension of home?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds to me like it's an extension ***of*** [the] home.

Comment: Your question needs more info or context for us to understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Beth, did you notice you have in there "to…" and "from…" and "of…" home but no useful context?

My guess would be "of" and that's a guess…

Answer (score -1):

I have never heard the expression *extension from home*, but I've often heard the expression *extension of (the) home*

While by no means definitive, and only in relation to books, [Google Books Ngram Search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=extension%20of%20the%20home%2Cextension%20of%20home%2Cextension%20from%20home&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cextension%20of%20the%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cextension%20of%20home%3B%2Cc0) doesn't show any significant hits for "from home" (it's not even charted):

[image]

Some casual Google searching shows hits on *extension from home* in the sense of "access your office phone extension from home," whereas *extension of home* shows many more hits along the lines of "an extension of your home"—more in line with the "home away from home" sense you're looking for.

Comment: Why would anyone have down-voted Jason's clearly helpful Answer, please?